# purging wso2 apim metrics(WSO2METRICS_DB) data on-demand

Tags: wso2-api-manager

My wso2 apim metrics internal database is growing large and it is more than 2gb in size? Even though data purge is enabled, everyday it deletes data which are older than 7 days,  it is causing file size issues. Is there any procedure available to purge the data on-demand?

thanks,
Santosh

Comment: Are you using H2 database?

Comment: Yes we are using default H2 database.

Comment: Any reason running this in H2? WSO2 does not recommend to run this database in H2. You need to use production ready databases such as mysql, oracle, postgresql, etc. From database level you need to purge data.

Comment: Is there any way we can get those metrics without console. I logged into h2 database console but couldn't find correct table names where i can query for jvm, gc metrics. All i can find is system tables.